# im trying to understand how to deploy a smart contract relating to my coin

Tags: solidity, remix

I created a coin and I wanted to ask how can I deploy a smart contract relating to this coin?
if i wanted to have smart contract that allow dividend payments for example how would I link this to my coin?

Would it be in the code for the coin and then deploy or would i need to code the contract in a different (.sol) file to the token code and somehow link it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you must link contract together. But it's kind of one after another.

You deploy a contract A first.
Then contract B take contract A address in his source code.

If you want a dividends there is a smart contract for it :

https://github.com/wardesqwe/funds-distribution-token